# Creating two object into one array

Tags: java, arrays

Normally my code is more longer but I tried to explain my question to you:

```
 public List<Person> person = Collections.singletonList(new Person());
```

I wrote this code and got an array and I wrote the fields of inside the class:

```
  public String name="Paris";
  public String surname="Hilton";
```

Then the output looks like:

```
"person": [{"name": "Paris","surname": "Hilton"}]
```

However, I want to create two person name and surname like that:

```
"person": [{"name": "Paris","surname": "Hilton"},{"name": "Cameron","value": "Diaz"}]
```

How it possible?

Comment: Hi! Please [edit] your question to include all of the relevant code, a [mre].

Comment: Where are you expecting "Cameron Diaz" to come from?

Comment: @ScottHunter I think OP might be confused about how objects work and what `Collections.singletonList(…)` does.

Comment: OP seems be confused about a number of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add a constructor in Person class that takes two parameters `Person(String name, String surname)`
2. Initialize Person objects using this constructor `new Person("A", "B") or new Person("X", "Y")`
3. Now add the created objects to a list (or any collection) (not a singletonList)
4. `singletonList` can store only single object
5. If you really need singletonList, then you need to wrap the two(or any number of) objects into another list and create a singletonList that contains a List
6. Please check whether you are looking for `unmodifiableList`
7. `singletonList` or `unmodifiableList` does not guarantee the immutability of the Person object
8. If you need immutable behavior on `Person`, then declare `name` and `surname` as final fields and assign them in the constructor using the input values
9. For any visual printing requirements, override the `toString` method of the `Person` class

So the class will look something like

```java
class Person {
  private final String name;
  private final String surname;

  public Person(String name, String surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
  }
  
  public String getName() {
    return this.name;
  }

  public String getSurname() {
    return this.surname;
  }
  
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "name: " + this.name + ", surname: " + this.surname;
  }
}
```

Alternatively, objects can be created with default values and setter can be used to set the values (or even directly accessing the fields if accessible). Still its preferred to have a parameterized constructor.